# Passing lots of values to template

Tags: python, templates, mako

How do i pass a lot of values to my template?

Documentation taken straight from the [Mako Website](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-templatelookup):

**myPythonProgram.py:**

```
from mako.template import Template

mytemplate = Template(filename='myHtmlTemplate.htm')
print mytemplate.render(name="jack") #<- how to pass like 40 more variables?
```

**myHtmlTemplate.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p> ${name} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution works fine for like under 10 but i want to use up to 40 Variables.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not store them in a Python dictionary and pass the dictionary into the template? : ) Haven't played with Mako, but that is what I would do in Django.

Comment: where are the names coming from?

Comment: variables are generated within the python programm. I just started using mako / python but its not just for playing. Its a realy nice language but the api documentation is a bit weak!

Comment: I am not very well versed in html  so bear with me, are you trying to pass multiple names or create multiple variable in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

render() accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments, and an arbitrary number of keyword arguments.

From the information you've given, you should probably keep a dictionary of your 40 items.

```
mydict = {'name': 'jack', 'age': 42, ... }
```

A call to `mytemplate.render(**mydict)` will unpack the arguments, and then you can refer to `${name}`, `${age}` and so on in the template.

Comment: ** did not work but mydict==mydict but thats suppose to be the same